# Magento 2 - REST API filter customer data by address fields

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api, filter, customer-address

I want to filter customers in a country,state,city or street in REST API. How can I do it?

I am using the `/V1/customers/search` API Call. Now I can only filter by the customers default billing address values.

When I try to filter by address fields, it throws an error "Invalid attribute name: %1".

How can I filter customers by address fields?